# iOS Swift - Custom UICollectionViewCell in Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I've added a collection view to a custom table view cell and now I'm trying to add a custom collection view cell inside. I'm having no luck registering the nib and loading the cell in cellForItemAtIndexPath.

I've been getting this error:

```
2015-01-08 17:51:23.760 puma[9018:533346] *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UICollectionView.m:3318
2015-01-08 17:51:23.764 puma[9018:533346] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

Relevant Code:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        var cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CustomCollectionViewCell

        if (cell == nil) {
            let nib = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomCollectionCell", owner: CustomCollectionViewCell.self, options: nil) as NSArray
            cell = nib.objectAtIndex(0) as? CustomCollectionViewCell
        }

        // Configure the cell
        return cell!
    }

}

class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }


}
```

Comment: First of all, I don't see where you attempt to register the nib (loading a nib is not the same thing as registering one). Secondly, dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: is guaranteed to return a cell, so your if (cell == nil) clause will never be executed.

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand there was a difference between registering and loading. How would I register the nib so I can load it?

Comment: I think we should know why you are putting a collection view cell int a table view cell. It's a bizarre thing to be doing.

Comment: I'm trying to make a calendar - each week is a table cell and each day is a collection view cell.

Comment: Look at the UICollectionView class reference for the method, 
registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason this is popping up a ton recently. Add the following code to viewDidLoad on your table view controller:

```
if let myTableView = self.tableView {
    self.tableView!.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "NibName", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}
```